Is there a way to see through fog cloud
I'm trying to make a ranger Kenku who makes fog clouds in fights and then shoots them through the enemys throughout the fog but I don't know how I would go about seeing through the fog.

Hi Trøll3r4u2nv and welcome to the stack!  I am closing your question as a duplicate of the one I have linked to.  Duplicate questions are a good thing, as it gives searches more targets to find, so thank you!  Please read the linked question.  If it does not answer your question, you can edit to explain why and your question may be reopened.  You might also want to ask an entirely new question, such as "Even if my ranger can't see through the fog clouds they make, what is an effective fighting style?"

While you are here, please take the tour and feel free to check the help center for other resources.  Happy stacking!
